# open program from windows Tray

Tags: autohotkey

I made a script that simply opens or activate specific app.
it works great but I have one issue, when the app minimized to windows tray.
the Hotkey activate the **Else statement part** so it creates another instance of the same app.

```
!a::
If WinExist("ahk_exe Orzeszek Timer.exe") 
{
   WinActivate, ahk_exe Orzeszek Timer.exe
}
Else {
   Run, "D:\Portable\PortableApps\Orzeszek Timer\Orzeszek Timer.exe"
}
Return
```

I need help with script to trigger the **IF statement part** in case the app appears in system tray.

Much Thanks in advance)

Comment: Windows minimized to system tray are mostly hidden windows. Try adding `DetectHiddenWindows On` before `If WinExist` and `WinShow` before `WinActivate`.

Comment: **user3419297** thanks for your reply
I modified the code according to your recommendation.
there is a change. but the appear window isn't the app itself but empty window that seems to be related to the app itself
https://i.imgur.com/POJXDJN.png

Comment: `DetectHiddenWindows On` and `WinShow ahk_exe Orzeszek Timer.exe` have to be separate lines.

Comment: if this is what script expected to be https://i.imgur.com/7GAlDIf.png 
the empty popapp window related to this script. 
or am I'm doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
!a::
Process, Exist, Orzeszek Timer.exe
If (Errorlevel != 0) ; is running
{
    WinGet, WinState, MinMax, ahk_exe Orzeszek Timer.exe
    If (WinState = "") ; is minimized to tray
        SendInput, #bo{Enter} ; Win+b activates the tray, o marks the icon of Orzeszek Timer
    else
        WinActivate, ahk_exe Orzeszek Timer.exe
}
else  ; is NOT running
    Run, "D:\Portable\PortableApps\Orzeszek Timer\Orzeszek Timer.exe"
return
```

If the program has its own hotkey to restore the window, use that hotkey instead of #bo{Enter}.

**EDIT:**

If `SendInput, #bo{Enter}` is too fast to restore the program, add a sleep between the keys to send:

```
...
    If (WinState = "") ; is minimized to tray
    {           
        SendInput, #b ; Win+b activates the tray
        ; WinWaitActive, ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
        Sleep, 300
        SendInput, o ; o marks the icon of Orzeszek Timer. Try first of all manually which letter marks the icon
        Sleep, 300
        SendInput, {Enter}
    }
...
```

**EDIT 2:**

I downloaded that small portable app and this is working on my system:

```
!a::
Process, Exist, Orzeszek Timer.exe
If (Errorlevel != 0)    ; is running
{
    WinGet, WinState, MinMax, ahk_exe Orzeszek Timer.exe
    If (WinState = "") ; is minimized to tray
        ; SendInput, #bot{Enter}  ; OR: 
        SendInput, #b{Enter}{Up}ot{Enter}
}
else    ; is NOT running
    Run, "D:\Portable\PortableApps\Orzeszek Timer\Orzeszek Timer.exe"
WinWait,  Orzeszek Timer,, 10
If (!ErrorLevel)
{
    WinActivate, Orzeszek Timer
    WinWaitActive Orzeszek Timer,, 5
    If (!ErrorLevel)
        MouseMove, 150, 80, 0
}
return
```

**EDIT 3:**

If you don't have the option "Always show all icons in the notification area" in the Settings enabled, try replacing

```
SendInput, #bot{Enter}
```

with

```
SendInput, #b{Enter}{Up}ot{Enter}
```

Answer (score 0):

**user3419297** much thanks for your script it works great. I Modified it a little to be open the app.

```
!a::
Process, Exist, Orzeszek Timer.exe
If (Errorlevel != 0) ; is running
{
    WinGet, WinState, MinMax, ahk_exe Orzeszek Timer.exe
    If (WinState = "") { 
      SendInput, #bo{Right}{Enter}
      Sleep, 500
      CoordMode, Mouse, Window
      MouseMove, 150, 80, 0
    }
    else
        WinActivate, ahk_exe Orzeszek Timer.exe
}
else  ; is NOT running
    Run, "D:\Portable\PortableApps\Orzeszek Timer\Orzeszek Timer.exe"
return
```

only one minor disadvantage the script depend on app been place first
in windows tray list.
of course I could always redefine {Right x} placement but is there more efficient way to find automatically app placement in tray?

Comment: Why {Right} after #bo? o should mark the icon of Orzeszek Timer on the tray if no other icon's name beginns with o. Try first of all manually which letter marks the icon (press Win+b, then o. If the icon is not marked try other letters until the icon gets marked). If `SendInput, #bo{Enter}` is too fast to restore the program, see my edited answer.

Comment: after pressing Win+b the the windows tray arrow up is get highlighted as should but pressing any key from a-z unfortunately lead to no result in my case.

Comment: See EDIT 3 in my answer.

Comment: The technique of searching for a letter to activate an icon does not appear to work anymore in Windows 11.  Navigating the tray overflow window appears to be by arrow-key only now.  Anyone know of a workaround?  The problem is that the layout of the icons is not deterministic, so the sequence of arrow keys needed to reach a given icon cannot be hardcoded into an AHK script ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

finally works! the only missing part in script was {Up} key as pointed on edit 3 for system tray to become searchable. so now I had no problem to find the exact key. in my case it was

```
            SendInput, #b{Enter}{Up}tt
            Sleep, 100
            SendInput, {Enter}
```

I Really don't know how to thank you. you helped me alot )